# One-Hot-Coding for factors defined through several columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, multiple-columns, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying different methods of clustering for scientific journals and I have a dataframe with this structure:

```
'data.frame':   30883 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Title        : chr  "CA - A Cancer Journal for Clinicians" "MMWR. Recommendations and reports : Morbidity and mortality weekly report. Recommendations and reports / Centers for Disease Co"| __truncated__ "Nature Reviews Materials" "Quarterly Journal of Economics" ...
 $ ISSN1        : chr  "15424863" "10575987" "20588437" "00335533" ...
 $ ISSN2        : chr  "00079235" "15458601" NA "15314650" ...
 $ SubCat1      : chr  "Hematology" "Epidemiology" "Biomaterials" "Economics and Econometrics " ...
 $ SubCat2      : chr  "Oncology " "Health Information Management" "Electronic, Optical and Magnetic Materials" NA ...
 $ SubCat3      : chr  NA "Health social science" "Energy" NA ...
 $ SubCat4      : chr  NA "Health, Toxicology and Mutagenesis" "Materials Chemistry" NA ...
 $ SubCat5      : chr  NA "Medicine " "Surfaces, Coatings and Films " NA ...
 $ SubCat6      : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Top.Level    : chr  "Health Sciences" "Health Sciences" "Physical Sciences and Engineering" "Social Sciences and Humanities" ...
 $ Primary.Level: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
```

My problem is elements in SubCat columns are in no particular order, meaning that, for example, Oncology may appear in any of those 6 columns even though it would be the same category despite the column number. For example, let's day SubCat1 has 136 different terms, but 80 of those are in common with SubCat4, which has 240 different terms. As a whole, both columns level up to 136+240-80 different factors.

I want to 1-hot-encode all 6 SubCat columns, so I have a column for each different factor in all 6 SubCat columns (no matter if it appears in several columns, I want a single column for it). I'm trying to avoid manually programming everything via for and dplyr operations, but thus far I haven't found any straightforwards method (I usually end up with a 1hotcod per column combined for all six columns, meaning a lot of duplicated columns).

Is there any elegant way around this problem? Maybe I'm asking something obvious, but I haven't found it yet...

Thanks

Edit: here are some rows with repetition in "Oncology":

```
dput(p[1:10, ])
structure(list(Title = c("Cancer Treatment Reviews", "npj Breast Cancer", 
"Journal of Thoracic Oncology", "International Journal of Radiation Oncology Biology Physics", 
"Radiotherapy and Oncology", "Prostate Cancer and Prostatic Diseases", 
"Oral Oncology", "Lung Cancer", "Annals of Surgical Oncology", 
"Frontiers in Oncology"), ISSN1 = c("03057372", "23744677", "15561380", 
"03603016", "18790887", "13657852", "18790593", "01695002", "10689265", 
"2234943X"), ISSN2 = c(NA, NA, "15560864", "1879355X", "01678140", 
"14765608", "13688375", "18728332", "15344681", NA), SubCat1 = c("Medicine", 
"Oncology", "Medicine", "Cancer Research", "Hematology", "Cancer Research", 
"Cancer Research", "Cancer Research", "Oncology", "Oncology"), 
    SubCat2 = c("Oncology", "Pharmacology medical", "Oncology", 
    "Oncology", "Oncology", "Oncology", "Oncology", "Oncology", 
    "Surgery ", "Cancer Research 2"), SubCat3 = c("Radiology, Nuclear Medicine and Imaging ", 
    "Radiology, Nuclear Medicine and Imaging ", "Pulmonary and Respiratory Medicine ", 
    "Radiation", "Radiology, Nuclear Medicine and Imaging ", 
    "Urology ", "Oral Surgery ", "Pulmonary and Respiratory Medicine ", 
    NA, NA), SubCat4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Radiology, Nuclear Medicine and Imaging ", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), SubCat5 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), SubCat6 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Top.Level = c("Health Sciences", 
    "Health Sciences", "Health Sciences", "Health Sciences", 
    "Health Sciences", "Health Sciences", "Health Sciences", 
    "Health Sciences", "Health Sciences", "Health Sciences"), 
    Primary.Level = c("Medicine and Dentistry", NA, NA, "Medicine and Dentistry", 
    NA, NA, NA, "Medicine and Dentistry", NA, NA)), .Names = c("Title", 
"ISSN1", "ISSN2", "SubCat1", "SubCat2", "SubCat3", "SubCat4", 
"SubCat5", "SubCat6", "Top.Level", "Primary.Level"), row.names = c("469", 
"493", "590", "1208", "1316", "1535", "1718", "1769", "1856", 
"1867"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `str()` is really useful for understanding the structure of your data, but not helpful for giving us example data to work with. Could you please find a few rows (no more than 10) that illustrate the problem, i.e., they have some overlapping elements in different subcat columns, and share that data in a copy-pasteable way? `dput()` makes a copy/pasteable version of an R object:  `dput(your_data[selected_rows, ])`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pivot_longer` to get your cats into one column and then `pivot_wider` with its `values_fn` and `values_fill` arguments to count the respective categories without losing your other columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)
(df <- tibble(Title = letters[1:10],
              ISSN = sample(10000000,10),
              SubCat1 = factor(LETTERS[1:10]),
              SubCat2 = factor(LETTERS[11:20]))
)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    Title    ISSN SubCat1 SubCat2
#>    <chr>   <int> <fct>   <fct>  
#>  1 a     7361068 A       K      
#>  2 b     7988851 B       L      
#>  3 c     8771863 C       M      
#>  4 d      146888 D       N      
#>  5 e     9104811 E       O      
#>  6 f     3612300 F       P      
#>  7 g     3242950 G       Q      
#>  8 h     1225062 H       R      
#>  9 i     6462332 I       S      
#> 10 j     7363583 J       T

atLeastOne <- function(x){
    ifelse(length(x) > 0,
           1,
           0)
  }
  
  df %>% 
    pivot_longer(matches('SubCat'),
                 names_to = 'subcat',
                 values_to = 'category') %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = 'category',
                values_from = 'subcat',
                values_fn = atLeastOne,
                values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 22
#>    Title    ISSN     A     K     B     L     C     M     D     N     E     O
#>    <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1 a     7361068     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  2 b     7988851     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  3 c     8771863     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
#>  4 d      146888     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
#>  5 e     9104811     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
#>  6 f     3612300     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  7 g     3242950     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  8 h     1225062     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  9 i     6462332     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 10 j     7363583     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> # … with 10 more variables: F <int>, P <int>, G <int>, Q <int>, H <int>,
#> #   R <int>, I <int>, S <int>, J <int>, T <int>
```

Comment: Thanks!, I'll try that and see if if works for me. The only difference I see with my data is value repetition in columns (ej, first column ABDC second column AFGC, plus I have a lot of NA, as each journal only has a handful of categories, but I can probably work around the NAs.

Comment: The reputation should be fine. It might be good to add a `& !is.na(X)` to the first argument of the ifelse function to cope with the NAs

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm sure I'm asking something obvious, but when I apply the proposed code, it works perfect on the console, but the results are not stored in df afterwards. I mean, the Console output is like this (what I wanted):

```
# A tibble: 29,407 x 1,082
   Title    ISSN1  ISSN2  Top.Level Primary.Level Hematology `Oncology `  None Epidemiology `Health Informa…
   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  <fct>     <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 CA - A … 15424… 00079… Health S… NA                     1           1     1            0                0
 2 MMWR. R… 10575… 15458… Health S… NA                     0           0     1            1                1
 3 Nature … 20588… NA     Physical… NA                     0           0     1            0                0
 4 Quarter… 00335… 15314… Social S… NA                     0           0     1            0                0
 5 Nature … 14710… 14710… Health S… NA                     0           0     1            0                0
 6 Nationa… 15518… 15518… Social S… NA                     0           0     1            0                0
 7 Nature … 14710… 14710… Health S… NA                     0           0     1            0                0
 8 Cell     00928… 10974… Life Sci… Biochemistry…          0           0     1            0                0
```

but df still shows only 11 columns in the environment. Furthermore, if I write df[1,] I get:

```
df[1,]
                                 Title    ISSN1    ISSN2    SubCat1   SubCat2 SubCat3 SubCat4 SubCat5
1 CA - A Cancer Journal for Clinicians 15424863 00079235 Hematology Oncology     None    None    None
  SubCat6       Top.Level Primary.Level
1    None Health Sciences          <NA>
```

BUT if I use dput(df[1,]) I get the whole thing (1082 columns).
Am I doing something wrong? What is really inside df after I apply the code? My plan was to cluster the rows depending on the SubCat columns, so I need to pass them to the algorithm somehow, but I can't refer to them like df[i,]

Sorry if this is obvious, but it had never happened to me.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apologies, I already solved it. A problem with %>% I guess